# Add a constraint so one date is not less than or equal to the other date in the same table in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am on `Server version: 5.6.10-log - MySQL Community Server (GPL)`

When I try to add this constrain I don't get an error, but it doesn't prevent the dates from failing the rule:

```
ALTER TABLE events ADD CONSTRAINT check_dates check (events.end_datetime <= events.extended_end_datetime);
```

Is it my server version? Is there any way to do this on my current version of mysql?

Comment: I don't think CHECK constraints are available in older MySQL versions. Try to update your MySQL server to a more recent version.

Comment: Alternatively, you can simply build the logic into the INSERT itself

Comment: 'Prior to MySQL 8.0.16, CREATE TABLE permits only the following limited version of table CHECK constraint syntax, which is parsed and ignored:' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html (not hard to find)

Comment: Thank you I guess I was hoping there was another way with a trigger or something. It's not possible to upgrade the database at this time, but maybe soon.